# Pass Data With Array in Laravel 6?

Tags: laravel, codeigniter, view, model, controller

In CodeIgniter 3.x, we can pass data with array by using this code:

```
$data=array(
   'apartment' => $this->apartmentmodel->get_all(),
   'title' => "List Apartement"
);
$this->load->view('apartment/index',$data);
```

But, this code is not working when implement on my Laravel 6 project

```
$data=array(
   'apartment' => DB::table('apartment')->get();,
   'title' => "List Apartement"
);
return view(apartment.index,$data);
```

What is the problem and how to fix it? Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 3):

Just remove `;` from line number 2 before `,` your it will be work

```
$data=array(
   'apartment' => DB::table('apartment')->get(),
   'title' => "List Apartement"
);
return view('apartment.index', $data);
```

or you can use compact too, see below docs
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/views

Comment: I felt so depressed I didn't realize that, thanks bro, it's work for me :D

Comment: with quotes 'apartment.index'

Comment: @AbuUbaidillah if this worked then please make my answer *accepted*

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel we can use eloquent for fetch data from database.

```
$data=[
   'apartment' => Apartment::get();,
   'title' => "List Apartment"
];

return view('apartment.index', ['data' => $data]);
```

It will help full for you.

Thanks

PHpanchal

Answer (score 0):

```
return view('apartment.index',compact('data'));
```

Comment: Please avoid code-only answers. Add a brief text explaining how this solves the issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `compact()` method, and you have an error (if this is project code).

Try:

```
$apartment = DB::table('apartment')->get();
$title = 'List Apartement';

return view('apartment.index', compact('apartment', 'title'));
```

Or

```
$data=[
   'apartment' => DB::table('apartment')->get();,
   'title' => "List Apartement"
];

return view('apartment.index', compact('data'));
```

Or:

```
$data=[
   'apartment' => DB::table('apartment')->get();,
   'title' => "List Apartement"
];

return view('apartment.index', ['data' => $data]);
```

Update:

In template file you can use it by calling `$data`, because in return statement you pass the variable name that will be shared with current template. So, to get some data from your array `$data` you just need to do:

```
@foreach($data['apartment'] as $apartment)
{{ $apartment }}
@endforeach
```

And to get your title use `$data['title']` as well

Comment: i'am using third option, but i confused to display apartment foreach, i'am use `@foreach ($apartment as $apartment) ... @endforeach`, is that wrong? error message: Undefined variable: apartment

Comment: have you tried to print variable in blade file like this `@php print_r($variableName); exit;@endphp`

Comment: You should use NOT just `$apartment`, but `$data['apartment']` because you pass to template `$data` array, and it contains key `apartment`

Comment: fyi, when using `return view('apartment.index',$data);` (and $data is an array like OP had it) there is no need to use `$data[..]` in your blade file, `$data`s keys will be available as variables inside blade